# How to handle an HR breach in confidentiality?

Tags: human-resources

I am in a situation where the HR Director told another employee something that happened between me and my boss, who is the CEO. The situation had nothing to do with the other employee.

What possible strategies do I have for dealing with and resolving this?

Comment: VTC We are neither lawyers nor psychics.  We cannot tell you what to do and we cannot give out legal advice.

Comment: Been there... Started looking for a new job. Found one. Quit. But that was just one of the symptoms of a bad place to work at.

Comment: Probably best to look for a new job. We can't advise you as far as the politics of the situation is concerned.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "something that happened with between me and my boss"? It's hard to give a good answer without really knowing the context.

Comment: @Lumberjack Vote To Close

Comment: -1 This has the potential to be an interesting question, but it needs additional info.  What was the information that was shared?  Do you have any insight into why the information was shared?

Comment: What would be an acceptable resolution for you? e.g. do you want an apology from the HR director?

Answer (score 6):

The best strategy for addressing this is to speak to the HR director and ask why that information was shared.  If they have no plausible reason then you can approach the CEO regarding their lack of professionalism.

This could be a one off mistake, one bad apple, or a symptom of a larger cultural problem.  I would take the advice to leave with a grain of salt.  Actually talking to them about the problem may result in a satisfactory conclusion to the issue.